# Alterar elemento de um modal depois de carregado - WP JS jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Boas, procura alguém que me ajude a entender esse dilema.

Tenho um modal que é carregado a partir de um click em um link e mostra as informações de um determinado curso. Até ai tudo certo e funcionando.

Porem, depois que esse modal já estiver carregado e exibindo os valores, quero alterar o texto do titulo por exemplo (h2). Se eu executar o codigo de alteração via console tudo funciona correto. porem de forma automática não, assim entendo que deve ser ordem de carregamento ou coisa parecida.
Já tentei todas as opções abaixo sem sucesso. Alguma sugestão?

```js
  /* TESTE 1 */
    jQuery(document).on('click','.mec-monthly-tooltip', function(){

        jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
        alert('Teste 1');
    });


  /* TESTE 2 */
    jQuery('.mec-calendar-day h4.mec-event-title').bind('click', function(e) {

        $(this).one("ajaxStop", function() {
            jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
            alert('Teste 2');
        }); 
    });
    
  /* TESTE 3 */
    jQuery(document).on('click','.mec-monthly-tooltip', function(){

        jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
        alert('Teste 3');
    });
    
  /* TESTE 4 */
  jQuery('h1.mec-single-title').bind('load', function() { 

        jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
        alert('Teste 4');
    });
    
  /* TESTE 5 */
    jQuery(window).load(function(){

        jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
        alert('Teste 5');
    });
```

Comment: Eu diria que a melhor estratégia seria colocar um event listener no modal. Mas sem outros detalhes (como se o código HTML do modal já está no DOM ou se é carregado dinamicamente), fica difícil elaborar uma resposta mais completa? Você poderia dar um pouco mais detalhes que nos ajude a encontrar uma solução? Talvez compartilhar o código HTML no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: infelizmente não tenho acesso ao código que gera o modal, é um plugin do wordpress. Nesta página você tem o calendário (vá ao mes de dezembro e clique no evento) para visualizar o modal. groupsd.pt/sentidos-dinamicos/formacao -  preciso alterar aquele titulo.   Meu código no console funciona, não estou conseguindo interceptar quando o moda é carregado para realizar a alteração

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't get any solution via JS or Jquery, a colleague gave the tip to hide via CSS the first 4 elements and it worked.

```
body h4.mec-event-title {
   text-indent: -32px;
}
```